# How to make my tree view display the data even after go into the child page?

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I got a design of tree view in MVC Layout with using bootstrap and jquery in it. I got a "Master" text in tree view parent inside got "Details1" as Child 1 / "details2" as child 2 . What is my issue is, whenever I click the "Details1 "(child1), it takes me to the Details 1 page , but all the child classes wrap up and collapse back with the parent in my tree view. I want my child data's to be collapsed with the parent data, only during page load and whenever we click the parent. All other time and whenever we click child page link, I don't want data's to be collapsed and I want all child class displays below the parent.How to make it.?

the code we used for our tree view is below..

```
<ul class="sidebar-menu">
                    <li class="treeview">
                        <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-clipboard" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Masters</span> <span class="pull-right-container"><i class="fa fa-angle-right pull-right"></i></span></a>
                        <ul class="treeview-menu">
                            <li><a href="/Detail1"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Detail1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/Detail2"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Detail2</a></li></ul>
```

Comment: You can use make use of class ='active'

Comment: may I know where to put the active class? Inside the treeview-menu can?

Comment: Yes I believe it should be on root element

Comment: Its Working.. Thank you ..I gave on root treeview as active. but, Only issue is when I open the page also,it display all, but during the initial page load all need to be collapsed.. later on only, all need to display.. Thank you so much for this, but Is there any other ways to fix the above issue also?

Comment: U can make two ways !!
1. Using jquery (on Click addClass('active')
2. Using #target also

Comment: sorry can you brief the above methods please?

Comment: please check the code below

Answer (score 0):

You can do either way I mean using JQuery or #targetid

```
<script>
$(function(){
   $('#child').click(function(){
   $('.treeview-menu').addClass('active');
});
});
</script>
```

OR 
using target id #id

Comment: I copy paste your code inside my layout and I need to call the id=''child'' inside my tree code inline right?

Comment: I just wrote Child as a demo id.. But You can choose whatever you want dear.. I mean on click of child element (id) open the parent

Comment: Yes you have to pass id='whateverid' and then $('#whateverid').click(.....

Comment: I am sorry, its not working. I use the same id name as per your class and I called that Id in my root of treeview.

Comment: Oh. I think you are not getting i am saying . On Click of Child element (id='child') and Add Class to root element ie. treeview-menu So it's quite simple

Comment: yes may be I didnt  get properly. ok. I am trying again and again to fix this issue using ur code. once fixed, I will let u know

Comment: I tried your code in all the way ..Its working.. But when  load to next page only,its not working.. I found the reason, may be ts not working because we call the function only after clicking the chile menu,so  after the page load, the function need to call again..